# Next JS Image component does't read image from local assets folder in s3

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, next-images

I am trying to deploy a next js application to s3 bucket with dynamic routes and ISR implemented . I'm using some locally stored images from assets folder in public . But after deploying it to S3 , it's returning 404 for the images even after the build folder has all the image files . Can anyone help me with this issue ?